# Looking for native CSS Files

Tags: visualforce, css

The Visualforce Developers guide states in the section on 'Using the Saleforce Stylesheets" that:

"The following stylesheets contain style classes you can reference. They are located in the /dCSS/ directory of your salesforce.com instance.

• dStandard.css – Contains the majority of style definitions for standard objects and tabs.
• allCustom.css – Contains style definitions for custom tabs"

but I cannot find them. Have looked through the instance URL, in Documents, Files an Static Resources. What am I missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use your browser's "View Source" option you should see and be able to open the URLs from there.

They will look something like this:

- /sCSS/30.0/sprites/1398193090000/Theme3/gc/dStandard.css
- /sCSS/30.0/sprites/1398193090000/Theme3/00Di0000000jPDO/005i0000002Xu6u/gc/dCustom0.css

though the timestamp and ID numbers may be different.

As they are shared by all apps, they are not part of any one app project.

You can copy and paste the minified content into e.g. [Code Beautifier](http://www.codebeautifier.com/) to make it more readable.